# Jinja2 - Use Set (Assignments) to call customer_function

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I want to call a python function from a jinja template. At the doucmentation (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/ see Assignments) the following example is offered:

```
{% set key, value = call_something() %}
```

But the following source does not work.

```
import jinja2

@jinja2.contextfunction
def hw():
    return "World"

template = jinja2.Template('{% set test = hw() %} Hello {{ test }}!')
template.render(name='John Doe')

Error: ... UndefinedError: 'hw' is undefined
```

Does any one knows how to solve the problem?! 
Thank's to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply supply it as a `key=value` pair in the [`template.render`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Template.render) function, just as you have supplied the `name` variable.

```
import jinja2

def hw():
    return "World"

template = jinja2.Template('{% set test = hw() %} Hello {{ test }}!')
print(template.render(name='John Doe', hw=hw))
```

---

*Alternatively*, if and when you plan to use a [Jinja environment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment), you may add it to the [`globals` dictionary](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment.globals) before any templates are created, should you want the function to be accessible from every template within said environment.

```
import jinja2

def hw():
    return "World"

template = """
{% set test = hw() %} Hello {{ test }}!

"""

env = jinja2.Environment()
env.globals['hw'] = hw
template = env.from_string(template)
print(template.render(name='John Doe'))
```

I've used the [`from_string`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string) method here to load your template, but there is a whole [loaders system](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#loaders) for environments which you may want to investigate.